# Map app not work , the map not load on device

Tags: android, android-maps

I developed an android map app (I'm using Android Studio). I tested on emulator and it works fine, but when I tested it on device, the map is not loading. Just shows blank tiles. Here's my code:

Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.exemple.impas" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<fragment
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btlocaliza" />

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Gerar Localização"
android:id="@+id/btlocaliza"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MapsActivity

```
package com.exemple.impas;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Polyline polyline;
    private List<LatLng> list;
    GPSTracker gps;

    private Button btlocaliza;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        btlocaliza = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btlocaliza);
        btlocaliza.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

                if (gps.canGetLocation) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    CreateMapView();
                    addMarker();
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position,15));
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your location is -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    gps.showSetting();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void CreateMapView() {
        try {
            if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
                if (mMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException exception) {
            Log.e("mapApp", exception.toString());
        }
    }

    private void addMarker() {
        if (mMap != null){
            gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);
            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").draggable(true));
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error creating marker", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

GPSTracker

```
package com.exemple.impas;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context context;

    Location location;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        try{
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled){

            }
            else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (isGPSEnabled){
                    if (location == null){
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location!= null){
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
     }

    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if (locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude(){
        if (location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude(){
        if (location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean isCanGetLocation(){
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSetting(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is setting");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled!");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witch){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                //context.startActivities(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int witch) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Someone can help me? Thanks Wendy

Comment: you post a lot of code which makes it quite hard for people to understand and reproduce your problem. If possible you should post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which makes it easier for the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something may not be right with your API key. Please post 1. your strings.xml file and 2. your LogCat output the moment you're loading the map, with Log level Error.

**Preliminary solution if it's indeed the API key:** (I had the same problem with my map app)

Try to load the map, look at the LogCat, it should say something about a wrong api key.

Near that line, it should tell you your sha1 code followed by your fully qualified app package. Copy the key+package to clipboard (looks like the one you gave google to create the first key, something like `3e:f4:ae:...;com.example.mapApp`.

Now go to googles dev console -> your project -> APIs and auth -> Credentials. Find your key below and click `Edit allowed android applications`. Put your previously copied code in here, press ok, and enjoy your now loading map.